# moment.tz.add() when using cdn to load data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am using moment.js to convert the date to local browser timezone.

```js
let theDate = "2018-09-25T19:36:15.289592";
let get_Date = moment.tz(theDate,'America/New_York').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(theDate + " = " + get_Date + " = " + moment.tz(get_Date).toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

My Result:
[image: Result]

I am not sure how to fix that error? And also format the local conversion.

Comment: [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) needs at least two parameters, you are missing the required timezone identifier.

Comment: @VincenzoC ok... but what do I use for local Browser's timezone?

Comment: You can use [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) that use local time by default or use native JavaScript Date. Which is the expected output?

Comment: @VincenzoC no... I want to convert `theDate` which is in eastern to local time. When I do `moment(theDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');` I get  `2018-09-25 19:36:15`. Which is the inputed datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Moment Timezone has no data for 2018-09-25 19:36:15` because you are missing the required timezone identifier when calling [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) (it needs at least two parameters).

You can use [`local()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) on moment object to display local time.

Here a live sample:

```js
let theDate = "2018-09-25T19:36:15.289592";
let get_Date = moment.tz(theDate,'America/New_York');
console.log(theDate + " = " + get_Date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + " = " + get_Date.local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```